# How to start VncServer on Startup

Tags: centos

I'm trying to get vncserver to start when I reboot my VPS.

I've done everything that http://it.megocollector.com/?p=1300 tells you to do, and I don't get any error messages.

But when I reboot my VPS, I still have to manually do  a "vncserver" in the terminal.

Vncserver is not starting up like it should.

Using CentOS 5.4.

Output of "chkconfig ––list | grep vnc"

```
 0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:on    6:off
```

A small difference is, where it tells you to do edit the $HOME file, mine is this since I use gnome

```
unset SESSION_MANAGER
exec gnome-session &
```

If I manually do `/etc/init.d/vncserver start`
in a terminal, it will run. it just doesn't run on startup.

Script in `/etc/init.d/vncserver` has executable permissions.

Comment: Check the permissions of the init script. It should live in /etc/init.d. Try increasing permission (execute should be the only one that matters) promiscuity and see if it starts on boot.

Comment: @ZacB Like this? http://puu.sh/P7m2

Comment: No...that's for the whole init.d directory. Find the file "vnc" (or vncserver or whatever) in the init.d directory, and make sure the "allow executing..." box is checked. I'm not familiar with the GNOME GUI permissions util. I'd say the safest bet is to open a terminal and run `sudo chmod 777 /etc/init.d/vnc*` and see if that resolves your issue.

Comment: @ZacB Actually now it's saying "audit_log_user_command(): Connection refused"

Comment: That's `sudo` complaining, not the `chmod` command. I guess you're locked out of Sudo on your VPS...which seems weird, but never mind; try running the command without `sudo`.

Comment: Though, the internet says that error is nonfatal, so the `chmod` is probably going through anyway.

Comment: @ZacB I didn't get any output.. is that supposed to happen? Output: `[root@nexpb ~]# chmod 777 /etc/init.d/vnc*
[root@nexpb ~]#
`

Comment: That's expected. Test to see if the problem was solved.

Comment: @ZacB Tested, still isn't running on startup